# I keep getting error on must be array type but it resolved to string

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

This is the code I'm working with and I got some errors I need help with so this code can work perfectly.

I got some errors on length cannot be resolved or not part of a field
the type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String

```java
package daintree;
import java.util.*;

public class daintree {
    String[] book = {
            "Absolute Java", 
            "JAVA: How to Program",
            "Computing Concepts with JAVA 8 Essentials",
            "Java Software Solutions",
            "Java Program Design"};
    int[] amount = {5, 0, 5, 5, 1};
    boolean[] eBook = {true, true, false, false, true};
    String cart = " ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public void addBooks() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter title to search for: ");
        String book = input.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < book.length; i++) {
            if (book[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(book.toLowerCase())) {
                if (amount[i] > 0 || eBook[i] == true) {
                    cart = book[i];
                    System.out.println("The following title is a match:");
                    System.out.println("1. " + cart);
                    System.out.println("\n0. Cancel");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("There is no title starting with that");
                }
                break;
            }
```

Comment: You've defined `book` twice, one is an array and one is a `String`.  Rename the one in `addBooks`

Comment: And start using a real IDE instead of whatever you're writing your code in right now, because it would have told you this even before you tried running your code.

Comment: Thanks, i am using eclipse and i'm still quite new to programming. thank you it fixes my problem

Answer (score 1):

> I got some errors on length cannot be resolved or not part of a field
> the type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to
> String

You have defined two variables with same name.

```java
String[] book = {
        "Absolute Java",
        "JAVA: How to Program",
        "Computing Concepts with JAVA 8 Essentials",
        "Java Software Solutions",
        "Java Program Design"};

String book = input.nextLine();
```

When it comes to the below line, programme is trying to check the length of the **String book** instead of the **String[] book**. Also in **book[i]**. Programme is trying to get an element from **String book** instead of the **String[] book**.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < book.length; i++) {
    if (book[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(book.toLowerCase())) {
        if (amount[i] > 0 || eBook[i] == true) {
            cart = book[i];
            System.out.println("The following title is a match:");
            System.out.println("1. " + cart);
            System.out.println("\n0. Cancel");
        } else {
            System.out.println("There is no title starting with that");
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

What you need to do is define the string array of books as **String[] bookArr**. Then change the **book.length** to **bookArr.length** and **book[i]** to **bookArr[i]**